# Where function on a virtual column in a union query

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I am new to sql and I need a little help. I have got a `union` query with 3 tables. I have got a virtual column so I can tell which table each row is from. I would like to be able to filter this virtual column to show only rows from a specific table.

I am using Microsoft Access and this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Table1 as Table_Name, Table1.1  
FROM Table1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT Table2 as Table_Name, Table2.1  
FROM Table2  
UNION ALL  
SELECT Table3 as Table_Name, Table3.1  
FROM Table3  
UNION ALL  
WHERE Table_Name = Form1.TextBox  
ORDER BY Table1.1;
```

I am trying to link this to a listbox on a form and then have some textboxs to filter results.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT Table1 as Table_Name, Table1.1
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2 as Table_Name, Table2.1
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Table3 as Table_Name, Table3.1
FROM Table3 ) q
WHERE Table_Name = Forms!Form1!TextBox
ORDER BY Table1.1;
```

See: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, spot on it works now, could you explain how this works. Thank you once again